# ng2-Pagination issue when pagination used for multiple bootstrap tables on same page

Tags: angular

I have two bootstrap tables on the same page and one table is in the main component and other is in the child component, I used declaration the services in the Module as follows :

```
import { NgModule }       from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule }   from "@angular/common";
import { CashierRiskProfileComponent }    from "./cashierriskprofile.component";
import { CashierRiskProfileService }   from "./cashierriskprofile.service";
import { CashierRiskProfileRouting } from "./cashierriskprofile.routing";
import { SharedModule } from "../shared/shared.module";
import {PaginationControlsCmp, PaginatePipe, PaginationService} from "ng2-pagination";
import { GenericExceptionComponent }      from "../shared/genericcomponents/genericexception.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        SharedModule,
        CashierRiskProfileRouting
    ],
    declarations: [
        PaginationControlsCmp, PaginatePipe, CashierRiskProfileComponent, GenericExceptionComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        PaginationService, CashierRiskProfileService
    ]
})
export class CashierRiskProfileModule { }
```

Above CashierRiskProfileComponent is parent component and inside its html used GenericExceptionComponent selector which is child component and both have bootstrap tables with pagination. The problem here is isolation of pagination between two grids, when one table page is change it is also changing page for child component table and vice versa. I tried to put that paginationControlsCmp , PaginatePipe in sharedModule but no use. I think this needs to be fixed ?

I think it seems to be isolation issue with ng2-pagination using Angular 2 RC 6, in RC 5 it used to work just fine since I used to use directives, Pipes in the individual components and it just worked fine since there is no common module that is sharing this pagination types, but in RC 6 directives, pipes are deprecated I can no longer use them in components but can only use at the module level which is causing isolation issues with pagination on two components on same page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see the html code but maybe you are using the same current page variable.

```
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p2 = $event" id="second"></pagination-controls>
```

Note the id="second" and p2=$event.

```
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { id: 'second', itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p2 }">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>
```

Here you tell paginate what variable to use.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/9cMKPK6fxHPnKRTaXTEQ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, It works. and not only current page. you have to set unique id for both, to make it works.